# Как осущуствляется выборка данных?

Tags: redis

Собираюсь использовать *Redis* в своём приложении.

Есть таблица соответствий `group2user` в *MySQL*, в которой имеются поля `id (primary)`, `userid`, `groupid`.

Мне нужно перевести эту таблицу в *Redis*-хранилище, причём так, чтобы я мог взять все записи с `userid = X` (так как один пользователь может состоять в нескольких группах).

Как это реализовать?

Интересует общая идея решения.

Comment: Лучше всего -- никак. Redis немного не для таких задач. MySQL подходит лучше.

Answer (score 2):

Так в чём проблема-то? Используйте для хранения списков групп пользователей множества, доступные по ключам вида `user:<id>:groups`.

Вот добавляем несколько групп двум пользователям:

```
> SADD user:1:groups 1
> SADD user:1:groups 2
> SADD user:1:groups 3
> SADD user:2:groups 1
> SADD user:2:groups 4
```

Получаем группы каждого из пользователей:

```
> SMEMBERS user:1:groups
1) "1"
2) "2"
3) "3"
> SMEMBERS user:2:groups
1) "1"
2) "4"
```

По этим полученным ID групп можно легко получить сразу пачкой сами группы, если они у вас хранятся в Redis по ID, с помощью операции `MGET`.